# How to make text slide in 2s after a block of text above it using CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to get some text to slide from the left to the center of the webpage using HTML and CSS animations. The goal is to have the first block of text slide into the center first, then after a 2 second delay, have the second block of text slide into the center. So that there will be a nice effect of the reader watching lines as they are written on the page.

Here is the HTML code:

```css
/* .slide1 {
  -webkit-animation : slideIn 2s forwards;
  -moz-animation    : slideIn 2s forwards;
  animation         : slideIn 2s forwards;
  } */
.slide2 {
  /* animation-delay: 2s; */
  margin-top        : -20px;
  -webkit-animation : slideIn 2s forwards;
  -moz-animation    : slideIn 2s forwards;
  animation         : slideIn 2s forwards;
} 
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0%   { transform: translateX(-900px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0);      }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideIn {
  0%   { transform: translateX(-900px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0);      }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0%   { transform: translateX(-900px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0);      }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="slide1">You want to go to the moon.<br></h1>
<h1 class="slide2">We’re here to give you a shot.</h1>
```

So the trouble is, the animation is working for the second line, but not for the first line when you uncomment the class slide1 above.
The entire thing moves together, which is not what is supposed to happen. The point of having a delay for the animation in slide2 is meant so that after the first block of text finishes moving into the center, then the second block of text will start to move right.
It's confusing why this isn't working -

- if you have any solutions to this, please share them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must first position your `.slide1` and `.slide2` off-screen

```
transform : translateX(-100vw);
```

...and contrary to what you imagine, the css commands must also respect an order and your `delay` command must be placed second after the global command of your `translate`

⛐  <sub>very very bad</sub> :

```
animation-delay : 2s;
animation       : 2s slideIn forwards;
```

<sup>( it make `animation-delay : 0;` )</sup>

*good* :

```
animation       : 2s slideIn forwards;
animation-delay : 2s;
```

.
otherwise you must respect the correct ordering of the arguments

```
animation : 2s 2s slideIn forwards;
```

but in my opinion the best way to write this - without repeating css:

```css
.slide {
  text-align : center;
  transform  : translateX(-100vw);
  animation  : 2s slideIn forwards;
  }  
.second {
  margin-top      : -.8em;
  animation-delay : 2s;
  } 
@keyframes slideIn {
  0%   { transform : translateX(-100vw); }
  100% { transform : translateX(0);      }
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="slide">You want to go to the moon.</h1>
<h1 class="slide second">We’re here to give you a shot.</h1>
```

also note the use of units, and the correct way to center your text whatever the width of the display (as you indicate in your question)

Comment: This was really helpful, Mister Jojo! Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very kind. If you would mind taking a look at another question I've recently posted about changing the background color of the Bootstrap navbar on this same page, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Sarah What about validationg my answer here ?

Comment: I don't know what validating is, but I upvoted and checked your answer (still unfamiliar with Stack Overflow). Is this helpful for you?

Comment: @Sarah SO is a widely appreciated site, having a good reputation score can't hurt your career

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the tip. You're the best!

Comment: I think I've figured out what validating is now :)